# How to prevent auto field to update when Sql Server raise error?

Tags: python, django, sql-server-2008, django-models

I have this primary key : transaction_number

It auto increment when I insert a model with a valid token.

Whenever I try to insert two models with the same token, I use the exception `IntegrityError` to ignore.

The problem is, if the current index from transaction_number is 5 and I try to insert something like 20 models with the same token, django will raise IntegrityError but the index will be 25.

How I can stop the index to update?

Thanks everyone

Model :

```
class Transaction(models.Model):
    transaction_number = models.AutoField(primary_key = True)
    token = models.CharField(max_length=32, unique = True)
    login = models.ForeignKey(Account, related_name = 'transactions', db_column = 'login', to_field = 'login')
    price = models.CharField(max_length = 7)
    description = models.CharField(max_length = 25)
    status = models.CharField(max_length = 25)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'Transactions'
```

Table :

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Transactions](
    [transaction_number] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [token] [varchar](32) NOT NULL,
    [login] [varchar](10) NOT NULL,
    [price] [varchar](7) NOT NULL,
    [description] [varchar](25) NOT NULL,
    [status] [varchar](25) NOT NULL,
    [date] [datetime] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Transactions_1] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [transaction_number] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of testing if the tokens are the same when you insert them, query the database to see if anything has the same token. If nothing is returned add it:

```
if not Transaction.objects.get(token=new_token):
       # do whatever
```